# How to call another HTTP request after forkJoin is completed (RxJS)?

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, reactive-programming

I have looked this for quite awhile, but I really haven't figured out how to do it "properly". All the other answers are either deprecated or do this in the opposite order.

What I would like to do, is that I want to send a bunch of HTTP request in parallel, thus the forkJoin. Then and only then when they are completed, I would like to call another HTTP request (which is now inside the submitOrder()).

And then at some point, if the first HTTP requests were successful I would like to mark my objects not dirty again.

This code works, but I've understood that this is really not the "proper" way of doing it, because it call subscription inside of a subscription.

So please, what is the real RxJs way?

```
forkJoin(obsArray).subscribe(res => {
            console.log('All were resolved');
            this.products.forEach(element => {
                this.isNotDirtyAnymore();
            });
            this.submitOrder();
        });


submitOrder() {
        this.service.submitOrder(this.id).subscribe(response => {
            console.log('Order was submitted');
        }, error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

Comment: could you not use switchMap after the forkJoin?

Comment: At least not chaining, as in forkJoin(array).switchMap() - complained about it not being part of the Observable. This probably had something to do with the update of RxJS.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of my comment above (not tested):

```
   forkJoin([
        this.service.callItem1,
        this.service.callItem2
    ]).pipe(
        tap(([resp1, resp2]: [any, any])=> {
            this.products.forEach(element => {
                this.isNotDirtyAnymore();
            });
        }),
        switchMap(([resp1, resp2]: [any, any]) => this.service.submitOrder(this.id))
    ).subscribe(response => {
        // if you don't need to do this in the tap above you can do it here
        this.products.forEach(element => {
            this.isNotDirtyAnymore();
        });
        console.log('Order was submitted');
    }, error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

As `forkJoin` actually return a new observable, you can just treat is as a normal observable. Then a normal hight order operator could be used, switchMap, contactMap... And put the side effect into tap. For example:

```
forkJoin(obsArray).pipe(
  tap(() => {
    console.log('All were resolved');
    this.products.forEach(element => this.isNotDirtyAnymore()),
  }),
  switchMap(() => submitOrder()),
});
```

Comment: And then I would .subscribe() to that thing at the end of it? Or does this already do it?

Comment: Yes, you can just subscribe() to trigger it. 

Or use async pipe if you are using angular. Platform level sugar will handle the unsubscribe for you automatically.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to results from the `forkJoin` you could do it like this:

```
concat(
  forkJoin(obsArray),
  this.service.submitOrder(this.id)
).subscribe({
  complete: () => { // This will be triggered only when `concat` completes which means both source Observables complete (won't emit error).
    this.products.forEach(element => {
      this.isNotDirtyAnymore();
    });
  },
})
```

Make sure you import `import { concat } from 'rxjs';` and not from `rxjs/operators`.

Comment: What if I would need the results from forkJoin? E.g. I would like to see if one of them had errors.

Comment: If any of them emit an error then the error will be propagated to `subscribe` where you can handle it with `error` handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pipe operator.

Example from [http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js%7EObservable.html):

```
import { map, filter, scan } from 'rxjs/operators';

Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
  .pipe(
     filter(x => x % 2 === 0),
     map(x => x + x),
     scan((acc, x) => acc + x)
   ).subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```